# Fullscreenr on image element

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to have a full screen image object, that will always fit the viewport size. The height of the image wrapper should be the height of the viewport. I have done that with the following code:

```
var hero = $( '#hero' );
var win = $( window );

hero.height(win.height());

$( window ).resize(function () {
    hero.height(win.height());
});
```

What I want is that the image element inside the wrapper will be always in the middle. When we scale down the viewport size, the left and right side of the image element should be hidden. I came to the following gist "fullscreenr". I have tried to recreate it for me, but it doesn't work.

The plugin only works if I select the parent, for me the id "hero". When I change the selector to `#hero img` it doesn't work correct. The image will be stretch so the image is pushed together, and do not disappear on both outer sides.

This is the code:

```
/**
* Fullscreenr - lightweight full screen background jquery plugin
* By Jan Schneiders
* www.nanotux.com
* 
* Modifications by Chris Van Patten
* http://www.vanpattenmedia.com
* Version 1.5
**/

(function($){

    $.fn.fullscreenr = function(options) {
        var defaults = { width: 1280,  height: 1024, elementID: this.selector };
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        $(document).ready(function() { $(options.elementID).fullscreenrResizer(options);    });
        $(window).bind("resize", function() { $(options.elementID).fullscreenrResizer(options); }); 

        return this;        
    }

    $.fn.fullscreenrResizer = function(options) {
        // Set bg size
        var ratio = options.height / options.width;

        // Get browser window size
        var browserwidth = $(window).width();
        var browserheight = $(window).height();

        // Scale the image
        if ((browserheight / browserwidth) > ratio){
            $(this).height(browserheight);
            $(this).width(browserheight / ratio);
        } else {
            $(this).width(browserwidth);
            $(this).height(browserwidth * ratio);
        }

        // Center the image
        $(this).css('left', (browserwidth - $(this).width()) / 2);
        $(this).css('top', (browserheight - $(this).height()) / 2);

        return this;
    }

})( jQuery );

$('#hero img').fullscreenr({width: 1400, height: 800});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code works fine if your change the

```
$(this).css('left', (browserwidth - $(this).width()) / 2);
$(this).css('top', (browserheight - $(this).height()) / 2);
```

to

```
$(this).css('margin-left', (browserwidth - $(this).width()) / 2);
$(this).css('margin-top', (browserheight - $(this).height()) / 2);
```

and add

```
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

to get rid of white spaces.

- the `overflow:hidden;` is not necessary, its just there to get rid of the scrollbars

here is an example using your code: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/La3XG/)

**EDIT:**

in your website, in the `style.css` page you have the following code:

```
img, a img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

removing it seems to have fixed the issue.

i have recreated your website in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/La3XG/9/), i have commented the `img, a img` code in the style on the right, try uncommenting it and see how it makes your background stretch.